# Count records which has no association or association of association meets condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Assume we have three classes:

```
class Person
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group
  has_many :people
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag
  belongs_to :group
end
```

It is possible, that `Person` may have `group_id = NULL`.

What I need, is to COUNT `Person` records which has `group_id = NULL` or his `Group` doesn't have any `Tag` record with attribute `status IN ('active', 'finished')`

One more thing, it has to be as fast as possible. We are querying over milions of records.

Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I have not tried this, can you please try something like this Person.joins(group: :tags).where("persons.group_id = null or tags.group_id = null").where("tags.status IN ('active', 'finished')")

Comment: If you will make a join, I will miss all `Person` without group_id.

Comment: hmm, yes includes should be use than to have left outer join.

Comment: 0 returned, I guess its because you want to search for `tags.group_id = null` and `tags.status IN ...`